# Save .pb and .pbtxt file from keras

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I need to get the `.pb` and `.pbtxt` files from a [Keras model](https://keras.io/api/models/model/) in order to use the trained Keras model with the DNN module of OpenCV in C++.

I can get the `.pb` file by doing `model.save('model',save_format='tf')` but I have not found a way to get the `.pbtxt` file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with the same setup and had the same problem(s), so here is what I found:

1. In OpenCV if you're using dnn::readNetFromTensorflow() then you don't actually need the ".pbtxt" file, the ".pb" alone is enough
2. What you're generating with keras model.save() method is a tensorflow SavedModel which generates multiple files (along with the .pb), but the .pb doesn't work alone and OpenCV doesn't accept the SavedModel format. So you need to generate a frozen graph. More info [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16582), and the solution to generate a frozen graph for [your model](https://github.com/leimao/Frozen_Graph_TensorFlow/blob/master/TensorFlow_v2/train.py).